# XSL get the attributes from elements with same name

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all, my english is very bad, but I hope someone understands my problem and can help me ;)

I have the following xml file

```
<fach>
  <fachname>Content Management Systems</fachname>
  <fachnummer>n/a</fachnummer>
  <semester>summer14</semester>
  <versuch>1</versuch>
  <note>
    5.0
  </note>
</fach>
<fach>
  <fachname>Content Management Systems</fachname>
  <fachnummer>n/a</fachnummer>
  <semester>winter15</semester>
  <versuch>2</versuch>
  <note>
    3.3
  </note>
</fach>
```

now we have to merge this into a HTML file and show it in a HTML Table. But the problem is. There are two rows. with the same name, but the other values are different.

[picture the the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN3s3.png)
There are two rows. The name is the same but the other values are different, we have to set all the values in one row.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual HTML you would like to be output (as text, not as a picture)? Can you also say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, the concepts this exercise is probably trying to teach you are:

- the use of `apply-templates` to process all of a set of elements (here, all of the `fach` elements)
- the use of relative paths to refer to children or descendants of an element (here, using relative paths from a template which matches `fach`, to refer to the children of *that particular* element)
- the recursive use of `apply-templates` to handle all children of the current element.

I won't give you full XSLT, since I expect you are taking a course and should solve the exercise on your own.  But if I were writing an XSLT stylesheet to process data like the data you show, I would write three groups of templates:

1. a template for the parent element of `fach`, which will write the `table` and `tbody` elements, and call `xsl:apply-templates` to produce the contents of the `tbody` element.
2. a template for `fach`, which will produce a `tr` element and call `xsl:apply-templates` to produce the contents of the row.
3. either one template for each possible child of `fach`, or one template with a match pattern like `match = "fachname | fachnummer | ... | note"`, which produces a `td` element for one cell of the table and calls `xsl:apply-templates` to produce the contents of the cell.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hopefully OP will appreciate the helpful guidance.